# Logging source code before output in Spyder console

Tags: python, spyder

When you run code in RStudio, it logs both the code and the output in the console (see [here](https://r4epis.netlify.app/images/RStudio_overview.PNG)). Is it possible to do the same in Spyder?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you running files in Spyder? Or selections? Or cells?

Comment: Ah, I think running a selection (F9) did the trick - it prints both the selection code and the output to the console. Previously I was using Ctrl+Enter, which only logs the output of the current cell.

Comment: Ok, I see. There's an option for that too but I'll mention it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can run cells and get their contents printed on the console by going to the menu

```
Tools > Preferences > Editor > Run code
```

and enabling the option called `Copy full cell contents to the console when running code cells`.